# How do I search (in some context) for questions that I have not answered?

Tags: support, search

Sometimes things are slow (no not here; I mean on smaller sites) and I go hunting for questions to answer.  I usually search by tag, but this of course turns up questions I've already answered -- which I often don't remember until I click through from the search results.

How do I search specifically for questions I have not answered?  I tried the advanced-search help but didn't find my answer there.